Is distillation inferior to reverse osmosis in desalination?
There is a research paper that states of how water was desalinated water using solar desalination and were able to achieve an efficiency that is 4 times faster than the thermal limit of 1.45kg/m2>/sup>/h by exploiting the photomolecular effect. With that in mind, would this make distillation by this method better than reverse osmosis or using CNTs, or is it still not that efficient compared to them?

What is your definition of efficiency? production? Cost? land area required? required labour?

what does "solar efficiency" mean?  Solar energy is basically free.  That said, the cost to build & maintain these plants is a huge part of justifying them, efficiency may not be enough.  Edit - stop it, @SolarMike  ;^)

Well, I want to compare the amount of water produced per m2 per hour, if changing the membranes used in reverse osmosis costs a lot and how much it may put it in a disadvantage. I also want to compare them in terms of how much maintenance is required.

No, it's not inferior. It's just a different niche. If you have any waste heat at all, or a good, underused solar collection area, distillation can work well. It generally requires a series of stages at different pressures to make best use of low quality waste heat, but the machinery is in many ways simpler and may be better suited to local self sufficiency and manufacture. One significant difference is the extraction ratio. Typical distillation plants run about 7-30 percent extraction. RO systems run 25-40 percent or more. So the brine concentrate volume may be a lot greater for the distillation plants. Distillation also has much lower dissolved solids remaining compared to RO.

https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/141350.2/IDA_manuscript.pdf?sequence=4&isAllowed=y
